# How to get the variable from aspx to aspx.cs [C#]

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, get

I'm developing a small app and I have a question about posting variables between WebPage.aspx and WebPage.aspx.cs .

I've got the variable from WebPage.aspx.cs to  WebPage.aspx like this:

WebPage.aspx.cs code:

```
 public string AdresKlienta = string.Empty;
 public string AdresPizzerii = string.Empty;
```

WebPage.aspx code:

```
var origin2 = '<%= AdresPizzerii %>';
var destinationA = '<% = AdresKlienta %>';
```

On WebPage.aspx I use javascript function that contains variables that I use do some work and I create another variable that I would like to post back (WebPage.aspx -> WebPage.aspx.cs).

I've been searching on the Internet for the solution, but found nothing. I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Posting back a variable simply involves putting it in a form element somewhere.  So let's say you create a form element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="someElement" id="someElement" />
```

Then in your JavaScript code you would set the value of that element:

```
document.getElementById('someElement').value = someValue;
```

When the form containing that element posts to a server-side resource, that resource can then access that value:

```
var someValue = Request.Form["someElement"];
```

The point is that in order for server-side code to receive any values from client-side code, those values need to be included in a request to the server of some kind.  Whether it's a form POST, a query string value on a GET request (from a redirect or clicking a link), an AJAX request in the background, etc.  The client-side code needs to make a new request to the server-side code in order to send it that value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden field, using javascript you can enter a value to this field and can be accessed from your code behind also.